# import utf8 csv to database

Tags: mysql, csv

i have database with utf8_persian_ci unicode

when i insert data with php . word save like below

```
Ù…ÙˆØ¨Ø§ÛŒÙ„ Ùˆ ÙˆØ³Ø§ÛŒÙ„
```

but in web page show correct

now i want import csv file to database when import complete

word save correct show  in database but in web page show ? instead of charecters .

i cant change database and table unicode .

how i can change csv unicode for show word like below word?

```
Ù…ÙˆØ¨Ø§ÛŒÙ„ Ùˆ ÙˆØ³Ø§ÛŒÙ„
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

before your insert query in php.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$query = "INSERT INTO test ...
```

It inserts and retrieves persian contents correctly into database.